# Can I share layout xml between two activities (Using Databinding with MVVM pattern)

Tags: android, android-layout, mvvm, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

Suppose I have Activity **A** with **activity_a.xml**. and I am setting the binding variable of my ViewModel **VMA**. I have another Activity B now I want to use the same **activity_a.xml** but with different ViewModel **VMB**. Now the problem is I can use the same variable name "ViewModel" for both ViewModels (VMA and VMB). And If I am using different-different variable name then How I will use them in same view property eg: `android:text = "@{viewModel.text}"`

Let's see only TextView case there can be multiple other cases where I would need ViewModel in XML

activity_a.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.VMA" />


       <!--
            <variable
            name="viewModel" I can't use same variable name as ViewModel
            type="com.example.VMB" /> -->
    </data>

    <TextView>
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
    </TextView>

</layout>
```

Now I want to use the same layout with different ViewModel type VMB in XML for Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange logic in your program. I can't understand why you need use different **ViewModels** with one **layout**?. If you are using same layout it's supposed that you viewmodel structure is the same, so you can just change data in your **ViewModelA** and using it with your **ActivityB**.

Comment: So you are suggesting, I should use the same ViewModel in both Activity A and Activity B ?

But if I want to have separate view models for Activity A and Activity B. The reason being both viewmodels have a lot of API' calls parsers and some business logic. But Ui is the same. 

I don't want to merge both viewModels because it will become huge and difficult to maintain.

Comment: I completely understand your point. Was just wondering if there is any alternative to do the way I want to do ?

Comment: You can use 2 viewmodels for different data in one fragment but why they need to get to one view in different cases? As advice maybe you can create dublicate of you're view, and one-visible,one-not-visible linking for different viewModels and change visibility regard of what data you want to use

Comment: Or if they parse to different views it will be ok

Comment: I think I should create one sharedViewModel for common code of VMA and VMB and  Both VMA and VMB should extend this. And then I can pass sharedViewModel to xml.